# How can i find element from the Image using Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to find an element for the bars present in the image but when i try to find the element the whole image is shown as an element. However when i hover mouse over a bar then then popup is shown. I need the value shown in the bar. So that can verify the same on other location.

Is there anyway i can do this? I am using webdriver with Java to automate this.

Here is the HTML code for the image. I cannot see child elements as it rendered as image only using(Dev express).

```
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_panelCallback_chart" onmousemove="__chartMouseMove(event, &#39;ctl00_MainContent_panelCallback_chart&#39;)" onclick="__chartClick(event, &#39;ctl00_MainContent_panelCallback_chart&#39;)" style="height:330px;width:500px;">
  <img id="ctl00_MainContent_panelCallback_chart_IMG" src="/ManageTRM/DXB.axd?DXCache=254a85bb-62ad-4ab0-8c32-9e4b53aefc4b" alt="The Aging chart showing Deferred series, Revisit series, Carry Over series, New series, Removed series, Utilized series, Centralized series." /><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$MainContent$panelCallback$chart$CallbackState" id="ctl00_MainContent_panelCallback_chart_CallbackState" />
```

[image: Console Page]

Comment: please provide the HTML of the image and its child elements.

Comment: @VivekSingh added in the question.